# Display function on VScode (windows)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, display

i'm currently doing a python course where the guy on the video is using 'display' instead of 'print', but i can't seem to make it work here, please help me.

The code:

```
import os
from IPython.display import display
lista_arquivos = os.listdir('C:\Repositorio\Vendas')

display(lista_arquivos)
```

The error:

```
PS C:\Repositorio\Curso Lira> python -u "c:\Repositorio\Curso Lira\Aula02.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Repositorio\Curso Lira\Aula02.py", line 2, in <module>
    from IPython.display import display
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'
```

code doesn't work as supposed

Comment: are you using IPython, just use `print`

Comment: You might need to install that package.  Try `python -m pip install ipython` then try running your code.

Comment: Thank you so much JonSG, it is working now !

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'

This means that `ipython` is used in your file, but the ipython package is not installed in your python environment.

You can use command `pip install ipython` in the terminal to install it.